# Installing protractor - Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode

Tags: node.js, protractor, npm-install

Every time I try to install protractor (http://www.protractortest.org), I get the an error. I am using the following command: `npm install -g protractor`

This is the error I am seeing:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "insta
ll" "-g" "protractor"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/node' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'protractor'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\protractor\npm-debug.log
```

I've tried installing @type/node directly, but that fails with the same error. I've tried downloading Typescript directly (and successfully), but that does not seem to satisfy the protractor installation.
What am I missing here? Is this package just not available right now (i.e. broken), it was updated 3 days ago, according to npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node

Comment: This is unusual. When I navigate to https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fnode on my chrome browser, I get a response and not a 404. `{"_id":"@types/node","_rev":"378-10c856ad75f410d40c03812afba9dc03","name":"@types/node","description":"TypeScript definitions for Node.js","dist-tags":{"latest":"8.0.14","ts2.0":"7.0.29","ts2.1":"7.0.29","ts2.2":"8.0.14","ts2.3":"8.0.14","ts2.4":"8.0.14","ts2.5":"8.0.14"},"versions":{"4.0.15-alpha":{"name":"@types/node","version":"4.0.15-alpha","description":"Type definitions for Node.js v4.x from` ...

Comment: I'm seeing that, too. I tried again, and it seemed to work this time. That said, when I tried to run the command 
`protractor conf.js`
I saw an error, "The term 'protractor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet..."
Finally, I tried to use yarn instead of npm. That worked. 
`yarn global add protractor`

Comment: Run this command  in terminal `npm config set @types:registry="https://registry.npmjs.org/"` and then try installing protractor.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous company we were using Nexus 2 with the private NPM repo as an option. All npm traffic went through Nexus, but it couldn't handle `@types` because is was supported Inna newer version / update. It gave the same error.

Are you also using a setup for a Private repo?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing native scripts. Try using the following commands:

1. set http
2. set http_proxy=

This will help you.